# Query to exclude the polygon which lying on given coordinate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

I want to try to use geoIntersects query and the result returns all the polygon which intersect with the given coordinate. Here my requirement is that I don't want to include that polygon which edge are coinciding with the given coordinates .

```
{ "geometry": {
    "$geoIntersects": {
        "$geometry": { 
            "type": "Polygon", 
            "coordinates": coordinate
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator to select the documents that do not *intersect with the given coordinate*.

```
{ "geometry": {
    "$not": {
        "$geoIntersects": {
            "$geometry": { 
                "type": "Polygon", 
                "coordinates": coordinate
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: This can not solve my purpose because here i am going to create new Polygon in DB and not allow the polygon coordinate which intersect with other polygon in db but if the given coordinate is only lying on edge of the  (not inside) then these coordinate are valid.